# Aggregate JSON files in Spark RDD

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a series of files that look similar to this:

```
[
 {
  'id':1,
  'transactions': [
   {
    'date': '2019-01-01',
    'amount': 50.50
   },
   {
    'date': '2019-01-02',
    'amount': 10.20
   },
  ]
 },
 {
  'id':2,
  'transactions': [
   {
    'date': '2019-01-01',
    'amount': 10.20
   },
   {
    'date': '2019-01-02',
    'amount': 0.50
   },
  ]
 }
]
```

I load these files to Spark using the following code

`users= spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(file_location)`

The result is a SparkData Frame with two columns `id` and `transactions` where `transactions` is a StructType.

I want to be able to "map" the `transactions` per user to aggregate them.

Currently I am using rdd and a function that looks like this:

```
users.rdd.map(lambda a: summarize_transactions(a.transactions))
```

The summarize function can be of two types:
a) Turn the list of objects into a Pandas Dataframe to summarize it.
b) Iterate over the list of objects to summarize it.

However I find out that `a.transactions` is a list of `pyspark.sql.types.Row`. Instead of actual dictionaries.

1) Is this the best way to accomplish my goal?
2) How can I turn the list of Spark Rows into the original list of Dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my own problem:

STEP 1: LOAD DATA AS TEXTFILE:
`step1= sc.textFile(file_location)`

STEP 2: READ AS JSON AND FLATMAP

```
import json
step2 = step1.map(lambda a: json.loads(a)).flatMap(lambda a: a)
```

STEP 3: KEY MAP REDUCE

```
setp3 = (
 step2
 .map(lambda line: [line['id'], line['transactions']])
 .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
 .mapValues(lambda a: summarize_transactions(a))
)
```